# Getting navigation to display the selected page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm struggling with getting my navigation menu to show the selected page.  I'm using the Bootstrap framework to build my site.  This is my navigation menu:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Digital Transformation</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">Transformation deck</a></li>
        <li><a href="/backgroundInformation.html">Background information</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

As far as I can tell, Bootstrap uses the following JS to make the selected menu item active, which I have in my header:

```
    <script>
      $('label').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
      });
    </script>
```

However with this code my primary nav item is active on page load, but when I select the second item it keeps 'Tranformation deck' as active instead of 'Background information'.

Am I missing a trick here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't see a label in the upper code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hook up click listeners to your nav items, your script should be something like this:

```
<script>
  $('#navbar nav li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

You don't have any 'label' tags in your code, so there isn't anything to attach click event handlers to.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(function() {
        // this will get the full URL at the address bar
        var url = window.location.href;

        // passes on every "a" tag
        $("#navbar a").each(function() {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
            if (url == (this.href)) {
                $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
```